# How to accommodate for add-ons in tfs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-extensions

I have to create a custom add-on to tfs. This add-on basically a 5 step process that needs additional forms that uses the data of users and manipulates it and saves it accordingly (CRUD).

I'm new to this so any advice, articles or links will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can start with the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the customized task is created ([Package your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts#step-4-package-your-extension)), it will generate a package (`*.vsix` file). For on-premise TFS server you just need to upload the extension (`*.vsix` file) and install it for your collections. Please see [Install extensions for disconnected TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#install-extensions-for-disconnected-tfs) for details.

Then users in all projects under the collection will be able to use your customized extension.

To create a custom task you can follow the steps mentioned in this article: [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops)

Microsoft also has created a GitHub repo with a number of samples and reading material to get you started, some tutorials for your reference (same for TFS):

- [VSTS Extensions Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)
- [Develop Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/index?view=azure-devops)